# Object transfer: Universal reference or by value

Tags: c++

Assume a class that only supports an explicit constructor or move semantics.  But not a default constructor or copy constructor.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int* _data;
public:
    Foo(int value) : _data(new int(value)) {}

    Foo(Foo&& f) : _data(f._data)
    {
        f._data = nullptr;
    }

    ~Foo() { delete _data;}

    Foo(Foo& f) = delete;
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo& f) = delete;
};
```

Now let's say, there's another component that needs to assume ownership of an instance of the above class.  An instance of "Bar" needs to take ownership of a Foo via its constructor.

```
Foo f(42);
Bar b(std::move(f));
```

So far, so good.

But how should the constructor of Bar be declared?  I assumed it was this:

```
class Bar
{
    Foo _f;
public:
    Bar(Foo&& f) : _f(std::move(f)) {}
};
```

But this also works:

```
class Bar
{
    Foo _f;
public:
    Bar(Foo f) : _f(std::move(f)) {}
};
```

**What's the difference and which is better?** (Or when to choose one over the other?)  I didn't even know the latter was possible until I observed Boost's Asio library [passing sockets to handlers by value](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MoveAcceptHandler.html). The socket class has similar constraints as the Foo class above.

Comment: `Bar(Foo f)` will make a copy of `f`, while `Bar(Foo&& f)` will not.

Comment: @Ripi2 - the copy constructor is deleted, so how could a copy of `f` be made?

Comment: In the first case you have a single move from `Foo(42)` into `_f`, in the second case - two moves, first from `Foo(42)` into `f`, then from `f` into `_f`.

Comment: `Foo(Foo&& f)` is not deleted.

Comment: `Bar(Foo&& f)` is not *"Universal reference"* (or *forwarding reference*). It is simply *rvalue reference*, `template <typename T> void f(T&&)` would be.